# Does the air temperature outside at the time of spring inspection matter when the tech comes to inspect and clean the inside and outside units?

Tags: hvac

I have semi annual inspections done on my A/C units both inside and outside. Will the temperature outside effect the tech's ability to properly clean and evaluate the operation of the units? The company always tries to set up the spring maintenance in February when it is still freezing outside.

Comment: They do this because they are not busy. Heating systems tend to have problems at the beginning of the heating season. Cooling systems keep HVAC companies busy through the entire cooling season. So February through April/May is dead.

Comment: Are these AC units part of a split system that may also provide heat? That might be the reason to check 2x per year if just AC sounds to be a waste of $.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, condensing units cannot be run when it's cold outside. The temperature at which the unit cannot be run will vary depending on the manufacturer's recommendation, and the company doing the inspection.

Answer (score 0):

The tech's going to have a hard time checking the superheat when it's less than 50 degrees Fahrenheit outside (most [charts don't even go below 55](http://www.achrnews.com/articles/83025-superheat-charging-curves-for-technicians)). That's assuming they even know what a superheat is, or have the proper equipment to test for it.

The 'superheat' is a certain magic number (dependent on your specific unit and type of refrigerant) for determining peak efficiency. Which is basically a given pressure that the unit needs to be adjusted to, (which, as I understand it, is mainly) predetermined by the length of your lineset - and is why you need a tech in the field to monkey with it because it can't "just come that way" from the factory. Rarely would any two linesets have the same length once installed.

If they at least show up with a jacket to put around the condenser, plus one (using a gauge set with temperature probes, +2). Otherwise IMO, this is make-up work, like Longneck says.

I live in Chicago. Coming to 'inspect' my AC in the middle of February would be absolute non-sense on so many levels.

Comment: Not quite right on line set and affect of superheat, for example a factory charged system will not need any change in refridgerent with a 10' line set or a 25' length only longer sets usually require additional Freon.  charts do go well below 55 for every blend I have worked with most go to minus 30 f and further. Super heat and sub cooling are not magic numbers but can indicate if the system is operating correctly but there are other factors that affect these numbers such the type of control capillary/TXV , if the coils are clean and the air flow all can affect the values.

Comment: @EdBeal - With +/- 15' of lineset, I'd make a bet that it's not flashing where it's supposed to (that's the point right?). I call it a magic number because (I've seen it done more than I have myself) after factoring in *all those variables*, there's a chart with a 'magic' number on it that tells you where to be. The last system I installed with <10' becamed overcharged and needed some recovered. I've never been a party to installing a system that couldn't have benefited from at least some tweaking. "need" is such a strong word ;) but it's what separates my company from the rest of the hacks.